# cannot retrieve json_encode value from php file into android

Tags: php, android, json

```
 <?php 

 require 'connection.php';

 $response = array();

 $response_array = array();

 $insert_query=0;

 if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["phone"]))
{
 $username = $_POST["username"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];
 $phone = $_POST["phone"];

 $check_existing_user = mysql_query("select * from eh_users where username like '".$username."'");



if(mysql_num_rows($check_existing_user)==0)
    {


 $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO eh_users(username, password, phone)           VALUES('$username','$password','$phone')");


 if($insert_query==1)
    {
        $response["success"]=1;

        $response["message"]="Insert Query Successful";

        file_put_contents("myFile.txt", json_encode($response));

        echo json_encode($response);

    }   

else
    {
        $response["success"]=0;

        $response["message"]="Error : Query not successful";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }

}
}

?>
```

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
        try
        {
            String url="http://www.iloveexpressions.com/eh/signUp.php";

            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);

            Log.d("Parameters ", username+" "+password+" "+phone);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username.trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone.trim()));

            Log.d("name value pairs", nameValuePairs.toString());

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            int success = json.getInt("success");

            //JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("success");

            Log.d("Json object : ",success+"");

            /*for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++ )
            {
                JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String success = c.getString("success");

                String message = c.getString("message");

                Log.d("Sucess : ", success);

                Log.d("Message : ", message);
            }*/


        }
```

the text file contains the right content {"success":1,"message":"Insert Query Successful"}

but i am not able to retrieve it in android

Comment: sorry for the unstructured way of posting the question . First Time

Comment: could you try to print what is the result of JSONObject json? and is there any error?

Comment: check response, is it null or not?

Comment: Debug and see what the json object is what you expected or not.

Comment: when i print the response the log cat shows this  org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@b239def8

Comment: and when i try to print the JSONObject json , i get the error Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: http://www.iloveexpressions.com/eh/signUp.php?username=user&password=test&phone=12345 gives an empty response. It should give one, with an error. I think it's a server issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to first do a log in using an url in `<new HttpPost.(url)` followed by a `httpclient.execute(httppost)` and use that url again with `getJSONFromUrl(url);`. Instead you should read the json from the existing response.

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
    sb = sb.append(line);
    }

String jsonText =  sb.toString();
```

Comment: what you're saying makes sense .. so i have to use the        Httpresponse response ?

Comment: the solution you provided worked perfectly but using your method the data i am getting on android is a string. If i wanted the response array which i have in my php file as a json object what can i do ?

Comment: No the php script does not contain json objects or arrays. It contains php variables and they are echoed as json encoded text. So you receive json text in a string. But having the json text you now take a json class to handle that json text and retrieve the objects.

Answer (score 0):

In my case .. i was using the Http methods followed by getjsonfromURL from the JSONParser class which also had the Http methods for get and post

I think there were two calls being made and thus there was no object getting returned